# geom_density (ggplot2): one density plot with different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

**[Edit] I have realized that `geom_density` may not be the best way to go for conveying the message I wanted. The plot was meant to visualize that 1) 50m has fewer event occurrences and 2) for 100m and 200m, the peaks of event occurrence are at 12. Would there be a better way to represent the data? The first plot @Alan has kindly provided is almost perfect for conveying such messages - but it fails when the data for 50m are too close to each other due to the kernel smoothing @r2evans has mentioned.**

I am trying to plot a density plot using `geom_density` under `ggplot2` that shows the number of times (proportion) an event occurs at different times at different distances. Below is the mock data.

```
data.frame(
  distance = c(rep("50", 4), rep("100", 98), rep("200", 98)),
  time = c(7,8,8,9, rnorm(196, 12, 2))
```

this df has 200 datapoints, 4 at 50m, 98 at 100m, and 98 at 200m. When I use `geom_density` with the df:

```
data.frame(
  distance = c(rep("50", 4), rep("100", 98), rep("200", 98)),
  time = c(7,8,8,9, rnorm(196, 12, 2))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = time, fill = distance, color = distance)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

However, looking at this plot, gives the impression that 50m is a lot more prevalent. Why is this happening? I wondered the function calculated the density per distance, but having the peak close to 0.8 for the 50m does not really make sense to me.

Is it possible to calculate the density such that the overall area is 1 i.e., the 50m curve will have an area of 0.02?

Comment: The apparent prevalance is due to the kernel smoothing of the density, and how closely the values are spaced. For instance, if you replace your `7,8,8,9` with (say) `7,8,8,90`, you'll see now that the density curve for "50" is now _significantly_ lower than the other curves. Bottom line: interpretation of the density curve when grouped like this should really be looking at the *spread/range* of the data and the modal suggestions (unimodal, etc). The relative occurrence of values within each group's distribution is interesting, but I think you're reading too much in comparative heights.

Comment: thank you. That makes sense. I'm not particular about the height, but I am just trying to visualize the distribution in the best way. Now I have read your comment, I think `geom_density` may not be the best way to show the distribution. The main message I want to convey with this data is that 1) 50m has fewer data and 2) for 100m and 200m, the peaks are at about 12. Could you possibly advise me on what kind of function/data visualization tool I should use to convey such message?

Comment: @r2evans I read this as wanting the three density curves to sum up to the overall density curve (i.e. if you used a position_stack you should get the same as the overall density)

Comment: @sheep are you looking for something different to this?

Comment: Yes @Alan, thank you for your helpful answer. Your suggested code worked for the mock data, but when I applied it to the actual data I have, I realized I still have the height issue -  due to the kernel smoothing - that because the 50m values are too close to each other, the height becomes really tall. That potentially leads to misunderstanding for my targeted audience.

Comment: Thank you again for adding some more content regarding the stacked density plot. While it will certainly be helpful for my future project, this is not what I'm looking for right now. Rather, what I wanted to express through this plot was the difference in peaks between different distances and the distribution of event occurrence.

Comment: i have added this to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aes(y = after_stat(density * n/nrow(df))` if you want the summed areas under all 3 curves to add to 1. Since you are piping the data frame, you will need to do `after_stat(density * n/200)` (i.e. enter the denominator manually).

```r
set.seed(1)

data.frame(
  distance = c(rep("50", 4), rep("100", 98), rep("200", 98)),
  time = c(7,8,8,9, rnorm(196, 12, 2))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = time, fill = distance, color = distance)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1, aes(y = after_stat(density * n/200)), bw = 0.5)
```

[image]

We can see this is correct by stacking the three densities on top of each other. This should give an identical result to plotting the density of the whole column without splitting into different color groups (here we show the overall density as a dashed black line):

```
set.seed(1)

data.frame(
  distance = c(rep("50", 4), rep("100", 98), rep("200", 98)),
  time = c(7,8,8,9, rnorm(196, 12, 2))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = time, fill = distance, color = distance)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1, aes(y = after_stat(density * n/200)), 
               position = 'stack', bw = 0.5) +
  geom_density(color = 'black', fill = NA, linetype = 2, bw = 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make the density values ahead of time with `density()` (or something else if you like) then scale the y-values by the proportion of the distance values in the dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(
  distance = c(rep("50", 4), rep("100", 98), rep("200", 98)),
  time = c(7,8,8,9, rnorm(196, 12, 2))) |>
  group_by(distance) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) |> 
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(scale = n/n()) |> 
  group_by(distance) |> 
  reframe(scale = first(scale), 
          d = list(broom::tidy(density(time)))) |> 
  unnest(d) |> 
  mutate(y_scaled = y*scale) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y_scaled, colour=distance)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill=distance), position="identity", alpha=.2) + 
  labs(x="Time", y="Density (scaled)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>